# set emitted value in compositition Api vue 3 nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I get the data from the component, but I don't understand how to get the data in the api composition. I can 't pass it to some variable . I can't return data from the function.

I'm new in composition api, also use nuxt.

Maybe I can use it somehow `useState()`

I just need to get the data in the function `addToBasket`

```js
html
<SelectSize  @selectedSize="selectedSize"></SelectSize>

js

<script setup>


let selectedSize=(val)=> {

  return val
}
let addToBasket=(id)=>{
  console.log(selectedSize())
  console.log(id)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `selectedSize` being a method, make it a ref: `const selectedSize = ref('')`. When the `@selectedSize` event listener fires, set the value of your `selectedSize` ref with the value of the `$event` argument that comes through to the event listener.

```
html
<SelectSize  @selectedSize="($event) => selectedSize = $event"></SelectSize>

js

<script setup>


let selectedSize= ref('')
let addToBasket=(id)=>{
  console.log(selectedSize.value)
  console.log(id)
}
</script>
```

Comment: But it nuxt 3, i cant use ref

Comment: You can, in fact use ref() in Nuxt3.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **ref()**

```js
const size = ref('');
const size = ref<CustomType>(); // or with types
```

You can set its value in selectedSize function

```js
const selectedSize = (val) => {
    size.value = val;
}
```

And then you can access variable's value anywhere inside script setup. In addToBasket function for example.

```js
const addToBasket = (id) => {
    console.log(size.value);
    console.log(id)
}
```

Check Vue docs for [ref()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref)

Comment: Maybe useState from nuxt 3 docs?